# Mock promise resolves to undefined when using react-scripts test but works correctly when running Jest directly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I am trying to create a simple mock function that returns a promise that resolves to a value.

```js
const mockPromise = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('example');

test('mock promise resolves', async () => {
  const result = await mockPromise();
  expect(result).toStrictEqual('example');
});
```

This works correctly when running Jest directly:

```
⋙ npx jest src/components/example.test.ts
 PASS  src/components/example.test.ts
  ✓ mock promise resolves (2 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.305 s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/components\/example.test.ts/i.
```

However when I run it using `react-scripts test`, the test fails.

```
⋙ npm t -- src/components/example.test.ts

> frontend@0.1.0 test
> react-scripts test --watchAll=false src/components/example.test.ts

 FAIL  src/components/example.test.ts
  ✕ mock promise resolves (3 ms)

  ● mock promise resolves

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "example"
    Received: undefined

      4 | test('mock promise resolves', async () => {
      5 |   const result = await mockPromise();
    > 6 |   expect(result).toEqual('example');
        |                  ^
      7 | });
      8 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/example.test.ts:6:18)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.93 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/components\/example.test.ts/i.
```

Why does the behaviour differ between the two ways of running the test, and how can I make it work correctly when using `react-scripts`?

Comment: In what way are you _"using `@testing-library/react`"_? Jest's still the test runner, and your example doesn't use render or any selectors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In reality, I am passing the callback to a component and testing that it calls it as required. However, I posted the minimal reproducible example to make it simpler to debug. It can be seen that when I run `jest` directly, the mock function works correctly, but when I use `npm t` (which calls `react-scripts test`), it fails.

Comment: `react-scripts` and React Testing Library are **not** the same thing. The former _uses Jest_, with some preset configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why it matters that the two ways of running are different, the official documentation of CRA does tell you to use `npm test` ; but to make it work for `@testing-library/react` try this:

```
let mockPromise: jest.Mock;

beforeEach(() => {
  mockPromise = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('example');
})

test('mock promise resolves', async () => {
  const result = await mockPromise();

  expect(result).toStrictEqual('example');
});
```

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge maybe my update will help you

Comment: I explain why it matters in the answer to the duplicate